# Find the area of the minimal surface between two loops?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

Say we have two loops given parametrically by $X^\mu(\sigma)$ and $Y^\mu(\sigma)$. We want to find the minimal possible area of a tube-like surface ending on these loops. It would be a functional $F[X,Y]$. And it also can't depend on the paramaterisation. Is this formula known or is there a way of finding this out?

I want to find an explict formula involving $X$ and $Y$ as an integral or summation. Because of the symmetries involved this should narrow down the possible formula.

We can think of this as two loops of wire and a bubble film joining them.

I suspect this is almost the same problem as the minimal area of a bubble on a single loop, since one can pinch a single loop to almost form two loops. So if one can solve the problem for one loop then this automatically solves the cases where the two loops are joined at a point.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no symmetry in your setting, unless $X$, $Y$ are both rotational symmetric with respect to the same axes.

Comment: There is diffeomorphism symmetry wrt the paramateristaion. Also the functional F is symmetric in the 2 variables. There is no other symmetries you are correct. I am talking about symmetries of the formula not symmetries of the system.